# Android widget:how to determine which button was clicked?

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, android-pendingintent

My widget has several ImageButtons, to set onClicked event for them, I use PendingIntent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Button1, pendingIntent);
```

If I want to use only one PendingIntent and Service for all Buttons, how do i determine which button was clickd?
Thanks you!

Comment: Wayne, we need the full code to work off of. This code doesn't say much about buttons...

Comment: I think that is enough :-?, all buttons was declared in xml file. I can set onclicked event for each button by using remoteview.setOnClickPendingIntent with different intents and services, it is not efficient so i want to use only one Service but I don't know which button was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to only use one [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html). The answer *is* to create multiple intents for each click. The simplest is to give each [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) a special action. This way you can tell the click events apart when you receive the intent.

Comment: I means that I want to implement only one Service, not one Intent. Maybe be i found solution. I will use many intent and just one service. To determine which button was click, i will use putExtras.
Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

> How do i determine which button was clickd? Thanks you!

**How about this? I added this code to my MainActivity.java file. My activity_main.xml has various buttons that depending which one you press it takes you to a specific website. I did not want to repeat the openWebSite() function multiple times so instead i tried v.getID() and it returns a unique value for the button that is pressed. I will use this unique number to go to the correct website.**

```
    public void openWebSite(View v) {

    if (v.getId()==2131230722) {
    String url = "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Emily-Otnes/110931118993282";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);

    }
    Log.e("test", String.valueOf(v.getId()));
}
```